# Verify: A derivative of a function has the intermediate value property

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $[a,b]$ with $f'(a) < \alpha < f'(b)$.  Prove there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = \alpha.$

*Note: Proofs are available.  This question is to verify, critique, and improve* this *proof.*

**Proof:** Let $g(x) = f(x) - \alpha x$, so $g'(x) = f'(x) - \alpha$.  We claim that $g$ attains a min on $(a,b)$ so that $g'$ has a zero.

Since $g'(a) = f'(a) - \alpha < 0$, there exists a $p \in (a,b)$ such that $g(p) < g(a)$.  For if no such $p$ existed, then $\left \lvert \frac {g(a) - g(a+h)}{h} \right \rvert \geq 0$ for all $h \in (0, b-a)$, and its limit $g'(a)$ must be greater or than or equal to zero as well.

By a similar argument, since $g'(b) > 0$, there exists a $q \in (a,b)$ such that $g(q) < g(b)$.

Now, since $g$ is a continuous function, it attains a minimum on compact interval $[a,b]$.  This minimum cannot be at $a$ or $b$, as shown above, and so must be in $(a,b)$.  Then by the Interior Extremum Theory, there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $g'(c) = 0$ and $f'(c) = \alpha$.

---

**Discussion:** I find it helpful to reflect on the  "behind the scenes" techniques that go into building a proof.  In this case, there are four:

1. To prove the existence of an interesting property of function $f'$, create an auxiliary function $g'$ which has a zero wherever $f$ has this property
2. To prove $g'$ has a zero, prove $g$ has an interior minimum
3. Do this by excluding the boundaries of a compact set from being candidate minimums
4. And exclude them by showing that if they were minimums, the derivative at that point couldn't be negative for $a$ (or positive for $b$), since non-strict inequalities carry over to limits

---

**Questions:** Is the proof correct, rigorous, and well written? How can it be improved? Is the argument proving the existence of $p$ sufficiently clear and robust?  Do you agree or have feedback on the discussion?

Comment: Replace $\left|\frac{g(a) - g(a+h)} {h} \right|\geq 0$ with $\frac{g(a+h) - g(a)} {h} \geq 0$. You can observe that absolute values are always non-negative so that your statement as written does not really help. I guess this is a typo. Apart from that I think the proof is fine and rigorous.

Comment: The only other change I can suggest is "Interior Extremum Theorem", not "Interior Extremum Theory". "Theory" is used to describe a collection of axioms and all the results that can be proved from them, not a single result.